# PHP: order a multi-dimensional array according to a list of values

Tags: php, arrays

Given this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => closed
            [userModifiedAt] => 2015-12-09T11:47:46Z
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => active
            [userModifiedAt] => 2016-02-08T16:43:26Z
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => closed
            [userModifiedAt] => 2016-03-31T03:47:19Z
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [status] => pending
            [userModifiedAt] => 2015-12-08T14:09:58Z
        )
```

I'd like to order it by [status] with this order:
- pending
- active
- closed

And for each status, order by [userModifiedAt].

I'm using this code:

```
usort($array, function($a,$b){ return strcmp($a['status'], $b['status']);} );
```

But it works alphabetically, so the status is ordered as:
- active
- closed
- pending

How can I order an array according to a predefined order list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This would be a trick -

```
## A array with the orders to be considered
$order = array('active' => 1, 'closed' => 2, 'pending' => 3);

usort($array, function($a, $b) use($order) { // Use the order array to compare
    return $order[$a[status]] - $order[$b[status]];
});

var_dump($array);
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["status"]=>
    string(6) "active"
    ["userModifiedAt"]=>
    string(20) "2016-02-08T16:43:26Z"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["status"]=>
    string(6) "closed"
    ["userModifiedAt"]=>
    string(20) "2015-12-09T11:47:46Z"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["status"]=>
    string(6) "closed"
    ["userModifiedAt"]=>
    string(20) "2016-03-31T03:47:19Z"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["status"]=>
    string(7) "pending"
    ["userModifiedAt"]=>
    string(20) "2015-12-08T14:09:58Z"
  }
}
```

Change the order `array` if you want different order. Key with lowest value will be first on the `array`. If you want **closed** to be first then provide the lowest value to it in `$order` array.

[DEMO](https://eval.in/546021)

Comment: Ok so you can do magic as well ? :) Didn't know!

Comment: Now on Beginner level. @HankyPanky :)

Comment: @Sougata thank you, that's perfect!